# WKWebView keeps refreshing same DDOS protection page

Tags: ios, gitlab, wkwebview

I'm building an iOS app and using the [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) library to authenticate through [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html). Gitlab/Cloudflare recently added a "DDOS protection page" (for lack of a better term) that reads "Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly." The problem is that after a few seconds, the screen flickers like it is trying to redirect, but then just goes back to the same "checking your browser" page. The expected behavior is that after this page, the user gets redirected to the gitlab login screen.

I have set up my ViewController similar to this [OauthSwift Sample](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/blob/master/Demo/Common/WebViewController.swift). My WKWebView's `webView(decidePolicyFor navigationAction:)` delegate function is being called with the url of "https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in", but the same protection page persists.

I'm thinking this is an issue with how I've set up my WKWebView since the issue does not occur on safari/chrome for mobile (those browsers correctly redirect). My intuition tells me that some kind of cache is being cleared on the redirect so the server thinks that this is a new request attempted by a different browser.

Relevant code:

```
class PublicLoginVC: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension PublicLoginVC: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(
        _ webView: WKWebView,
        decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
        decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void
    ) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        print(url)
        
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}

extension PublicLoginVC: OAuthSwiftURLHandlerType {
    func handle(_ url: URL) {
        let req = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.webView.load(req)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was setting my `UserAgent` like so...

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(object: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", forKey: "UserAgent" as NSCopying)
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dictionary as! [String : Any])
```

Removing `Chrome/41.0.2228.0` fixed it. I did some more digging into what exactly this "UserAgent" was, and my understanding is that it tells the server what browser we are using. I'm still not 100% sure on how sending multiple values in the string above works, but I'm fairly confident that I should only be using `AppleWebKit`.

I think the correct solution, rather than just removing that chrome value, is to set the user agent as follows...

```
override func loadView() {
    ...
    webView.customUserAgent = "AppleWebKit/605.1.15"
    ...
}
```

I'm still not certain that this is the correct way to set the "UserAgent" (it feels strange hard coding this version number), but it seems to fix my issue. If anyone has more context, feel free to share.